Final point count
When playing American Canasta, open with a wild card canasta and am not able to close it. Negative 2000 but do we still add up the point value of those cards either closed with 7 or still open?

You will still add up the point values of those cards. If you have completed at least 1 canasta, you will add the value of those cards. If you have not, you will subtract the value.
https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#american-scoring

Score for melded cards

If a team has completed at least one canasta, the total value of all the cards (other than threes) melded by the team, whether forming part of a canastas or smaller combinations, is added to the team's score. The standard values of the cards are used.
If a team has not completed any canastas, then the value of all their melded cards is subtracted from their score, along with the value of the cards remaining in their hands.


https://canasta.com/rules/

Score for melded cards

– If a team has completed at least one canasta, the total value of all the cards (other than threes) melded by the team is added to the team’s score.
– If a team has not completed any canastas, then the value of all their melded cards is subtracted from their score, along with the value of the cards remaining in their hands.


